# React-Native performance hints for FlatList

Tags: performance, react-native, hints, react-native-flatlist

I'm having trouble to scroll lists smoothly on relatively old hardware (Ipad 3 with IOS 9.3.5) although performance in newer devices is ok, I'm doing tests with approx 8000 items per list.

Any hint to improve performance is welcome, to make demo more simple I’m using images from the web, but in my real project I load them locally (although it doesn’t improve scroll at all), performance seems to degrade when I increase the number of columns, with one column the response is acceptable but there are some jitters anyway, my application require four columns.

Here is my app link:

https://snack.expo.io/Hk46ErZrb

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

This might help with the list options http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/lists.
Moreover, you can optimise the data you are importing like compressing the images and serving it via CDN.